# Capture query to MySQL in Server

Tags: web-application, linux, java, mysql, tcp

I want to capture queries to MySQL from my web-application on my Linux-based Server. MySQL port is 3306 and my web-application in on port 8181. So I started using `tcpdump` as follow:

```
# tcpdump -x "port 3306"
```

Now I browse my application and make some queries to Data-Base but I get nothing in `tcpdump` console.
I also tried this:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 -l -w - dst port 3306 | strings | perl -e '
while(<>) { chomp; next if /^[^ ]+[ ]*$/;
  if(/^(SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT|SET|COMMIT|ROLLBACK|CREATE|DROP|ALTER)/i) {
    if (defined $q) { print "$q\n"; }
    $q=$_;
  } else {
    $_ =~ s/^[ \t]+//; $q.=" $_";
  }
}'
```

But I got nothing either. I really don't know what is the problem. When I checked `servlet` code on my server, I can find Data-Base connection is established on port 3306:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    cnn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OTP?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "blahblah", "blahblah");
```

can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Since the application send local query to local database, in order to capture these queries I should capture `lo` packets with `tcpdump`:

```
# tcpdump -xx -i lo
```

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jet Profiler](http://www.jetprofiler.com/download/) for catch your querys and is a cross-platform program and you can download a free version.

Comment: Actually I have to use tcpdump because I check the packets on the server for pentesting and I don't have permission to install any tools. However thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

With following Query you can check, where the data is logged, and if the logging is enabled:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%general_log%';
```